# ExtJS Store Ajax Query in Cookies & Load

Tags: ajax, extjs, sencha-cmd

I am trying to store the Ajax request in the cookies so I can load it without the Ajax call if user refreshes the page.

So, this works: `this.successLoad(response);`

But this: `this.successLoad(Ext.util.Cookies.get('JSON'));`
doesn't work even if I set the cookie JSON to be equal the response I get from the Ajax request in success area. I tried to encode into cookie then decode the cookie but that didn't help eiter.

Long story short, I want to have a check if browser has a JSON cookie, if it does, simply send in JSON into the this.successLoad to load the page, if doesn't (it means user visiting first time) then create JSON cookie and load the page normally first time. JSON cookie is not setting up properly.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/Authorization',
    method: 'POST',
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    withCredentials: true,
    jsonData: {
        activationCode: "",
    },
    scope: this,
    success: function (response) {
        this.getView().unmask();

        // Cookie Creation Here
        Ext.util.Cookies.clear('JSON');
        Ext.util.Cookies.set('JSON', res);

        this.successLoad(response);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, cookies are plain text files and they can only be string. You can't store objects in cookies. Hence you need to encode the object using Ext.encode(response) as follows:

```
Ext.util.Cookies.set('JSON',Ext.encode(response));
```

Also while retrieving, you need to decode it as follows:

```
this.successLoad(Ext.decode(Ext.util.Cookies.get('JSON')));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! it totally makes sense but it's giving an error

Comment: ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1539093647244:55950 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Okay I solved that, it was because "response" was the AJAX response so it was gigantic. I read my code and realized it's using only part of that response so I created a variable and assigned to it like `var data = response.ID` for example and send that into cookie.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use Extjs cookie library, then you can use the following utility functions :

```
getCookie:function(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    },
    setCookie:function(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        if(window.location.protocol=="https:")
        {
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";secure;path=/";
        }
        else
        {
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
        }
    },
```

Place the code in some singleton to access name.Where cname is name for your cookie(string). cvalue is value for your cookie (string) and extdays if number to days you expect your cookie to expire (integer).